# Cannot POST erro express

Tags: javascript, node.js, express.js

Estou tentando criar um sistema de login, segue meu form:

```
<form action="/auth" class="login-form" method="POST">
  <h1>Login</h1>

  <div class="txtb">
    <input type="text" name="username" id="username" placeholder="Username">
  </div>

  <div class="txtb">
    <input type="password" name="password" id="password" placeholder="Password">
  </div>

  <input type="submit" class="logbtn" value="Login">

  <div class="bottom-text">
    Não ten uma conta? <a href="#">Sign up</a>
  </div>

</form>
```

Meu server.js

```
const http = require('http');
const express = require('express');
const socketio = require('socket.io');
const mysql = require('mysql');
const session = require('express-session');
const bodyParser = require('body-parser');
const path = require("path");

const app = express();
const server = require('http').createServer(app);
const io = require('socket.io')(server);

app.use(express.static(path.join(__dirname, 'public')));
app.set('views', path.join(__dirname, 'public'));
app.engine('html',require('ejs').renderFile);
app.set('view engine','html');

app.get('/', (req, res) => {
    res.render('index.html');
});

app.get('/chat', (req, res) => {
    res.render('chat.html');
});


let messages = [];

io.on('connection', socket => {
    console.log('Socket conectado');

    socket.on('sendMessage', data => {
        messages.push(data);
        socket.broadcast.emit('receivedMessage', data);
    });
});

//Login

var connection = mysql.createConnection({
    host:'localhost',
    user: 'root',
    password: '', 
    database: 'sanderson'
});

connection.connect(function(error) {
    if(!!error){
        console.log('Erro!')
    }
    else{
        console.log('Conectou :)')
    }
});

var log = express();
log.use(session({
    secret: 'secret',
    resave: true,
    saveUninitialized: true
}));
log.use(bodyParser.urlencoded({extended : true}));
log.use(bodyParser.json());

log.get('/', function(request, response) {
    response.sendFile(path.join(__dirname + '/index.html'));
});

log.post('/auth', function(request, response) {
    var username = request.body.username;
    var password = request.body.password;
    if (username && password) {
        connection.query('SELECT * FROM user WHERE nome = ? AND senha = ?', [username, password], function(error, results, fields) {
            if (results.length > 0) {
                request.session.loggedin = true;
                request.session.username = username;
                response.redirect('public/chat.html');
            } else {
                response.send('Incorrect Username and/or Password!');
                response.redirect('public/test.html');
            }           
        });
    } else {
        response.send('Please enter Username and Password!');
        response.redirect('public/test.html');
    }
});

server.listen(3000);
```

Meu index.html é o formulário, quando clico em enviar esse erro aparece.

Comment: Este código funciona? onde você declarou a variável `server`?

Comment: Funciona sim, server.js é o arquivo onde eu comecei as rotas e o express, porém na minha pergunta coloquei apenas a parte que corresponde a minha tentativa de login

Comment: editei e coloquei o server.js todo para ver se conseguem me ajudar

Comment: postei com as edições

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Em seu html você deve declarar as tags `name` e `placeholder` dentro da tag `input`.

Modificando o seu html temos o seguinte código:

```
<form action="/auth" class="login-form" method="POST">
    <h1>Login</h1>

    <div class="txtb">
      <input type="text" name="username" id="username" placeholder="Username">
    </div>

    <div class="txtb">
      <input type="password" name="password" id="password" placeholder="Password">
    </div>

    <input type="submit" class="logbtn" value="Login">

    <div class="bottom-text">
      Não ten uma conta? <a href="#">Sign up</a>
    </div>

  </form>
```

Repare que a escolha dos nomes dessas variáveis não é aleatória, esses são os nomes que estão declarados em seu módulo `app.js`, dentro do função post da rota `/auth` , vc usa os valores dessas variáveis para fazer a consulta no banco de dados. Por isso a declaração desses nomes.

Agora será possível utilizar sua conexão ao banco para verificar os usuário e senha

O código que utilizei em meu express foi o seguinte:

***app.js***

```
const express = require('express')
const path = require('path')
var log = express();

log.use(express.urlencoded({extended : true}));
log.use(express.json());

log.get('/', function(request, response) {
    response.sendFile(path.join(__dirname + '/public/index.html'));
});

log.post('/auth', function(request, response) {
    console.log(request.body)
    var username = request.body.username;
    var password = request.body.password;
    if (username && password) {
        connection.query('SELECT * FROM user WHERE nome = ? AND senha = ?', [username, password], function(error, results, fields) {
            if (results.length > 0) {
                request.session.loggedin = true;
                request.session.username = username;
                response.redirect('public/chat.html');
            } else {
                response.send('Incorrect Username and/or Password!');
                response.redirect('public/test.html');
            }           
        });
    } else {
        response.send('Please enter Username and Password!');
        response.redirect('public/test.html');
    }
});

log.listen(3000);
```

Comment: muito obrigado, mas eu acredito que o erro está no arquivo server.js, pois eu já havia definido a tag name, como você apontou só não coloquei o id, e o placeholder que na minha concepção é apenas algo visual. Fiz as alterações no html mas infelizmente o erro persiste.

Comment: Sim, já fiz a alteração, e troquei o span pelo input, mas ainda o mesmo erro.

Comment: até onde eu testei, a conexão com o db funciona

Comment: Descobri o meu erro, eu declarei duas variaveis = express(); , a variavel app e a log, fiz a substituição da log pela app a variavel que eu usei no inicio do arquivo server.js, e funcionou, muito obrigado.